# Android: poner un textView en Linear Layout en la parte inferior de la pantalla

Tags: android, xml, textview, linearlayout

Recién empiezo a estudiar con Android Studio y probé todas las sentencias para mi **`textView`** on **`bottom`** screen por **`LinearLayout`**, pero hasta ahora nada. Cómo lo puedo hacer? Ayuda!!!

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="You're invited!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="54sp"
        android:background="#009688" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Bonfire at the beach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:background="#009688" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ocean"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hola Vero. Bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial es el español por lo que has de traducir la pregunta, pulsando en [edit], para que sea aceptada. Tambien mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde Stack Overflow o accediste directamente a Stack Overflow en español? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y sería útil saber el motivo, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara, explicitando que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: Hola lois6b!! Primero te pido disculpás si ofendí o molesté por redactar la pregunta en inglés, no fue mi intención  y sí me registré por Stackoverflow en inglés porque estoy haciendo un curso gratis online de Android(es en inglés) y desde ahí te pasan el link para acá como sitio muy bueno para sacarse dudas, consultar etc. No tenía idea de que tenía que formular las preguntas en español, pero buenísimo que me lo aclares y me puedan ayudar, y ayudar en lo que pueda(recién empiezo a programar XML). Saludos

Comment: una ocion seria aregar la linea android:layout_marginTop="450dp" para que tenga n margen desde arriba del layout

Comment: Gracias, ahí probé pero nada, me dá error.

Comment: @Vero no me has ofendido ni molestado :P es solo curioso la gran cantidad de prguntas en inglés cuando este sitio está escrito todo en español. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Primero vamos a entender como funciona un **`LinearLayout`**..

**LinearLayout:** Dispone los elementos en una fila o en una columna. Dispone las Vistas una a continuación de la otra.
Por lo tanto las vista 'en este caso será una `TextView`' que queramos posicionar en la parte inferior, deberá ir en la última posición definida en nuestro xml.

> *Además debemos darle todo el espacio disponible y flotarlo en la parte inferior.*
>   Esto lo hacemos con **estas 2 Líneas..**

```
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
```

---

Te dejo el código de tu xml con el textview en la parte inferior

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ocean"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <TextView
        android:text="You're invited!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="54sp"
        android:background="#009688" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Bonfire at the beach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:background="#009688" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Y el **resultado**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Diego L o L muchas gracias por la explicación sobre LynearLayout es muy clara. La verdad lo soluciné sola, pero no hice lamentablemente no hice copia del código para ponerla acá, lo que te puedo decir es que lo hice de otra forma. Hace muy poco que empecé en esto de programar y participar en el foro, así que se me escapó a la hora de poner la respuesta. Igualmente me vino bárbara tu ayuda y la voy a poner en práctica. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Se agradece tu comentario. Saludos!!